# PowerShell Module Deployment

Tags: powershell, module, manifest

I don't know which profile location my users are going to deploy my module to. How can I define RootModule path in the manifest?

For example, one user may deploy the module to the PS Profile folder under System32 (All Users) and another may deploy it to the PS Profile folder under his Windows user profile (Current User).

This means the .psd1 file will need to be manually edited after a user deploys my module.  Is there any way around this problem (aside from writing a compiled installer)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `RootModule` path in the manifest file. Only a `RootModule` which is set to the name of your psm1-module.

[microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-module-manifest):

> Script module or binary module file associated with this manifest. Previous versions of PowerShell called this element the ModuleToProcess.
>
> Possible types for the root module can be empty (which will make this a Manifest module), the name of a script module (.psm1, which makes this a Script module), or the name of a binary module (.exe or .dll, which makes this a Binary module). Placing the name of a module manifest (.psd1) or a script file (.ps1) in this element will cause an error to occur.

Base on what you described it seems that you need an absolute path in your module. If so, use the `$PSScriptRoot` in your module. Check this [link](https://thinkpowershell.com/add-script-flexibility-relative-file-paths/).

Hope that helps.

Comment: The value I was using for RootModule was the full path to the .psm1, which of course would be different depending on which PS profile folder (Current User or All Users) the module folder was copied to.

Comment: The solution was to correct the PSModulePath `$env:PSModulePath` on my test workstation. By default, PSModulePath should include both Current User and All Users profile folders.  While the value for RootModule **can** be the full path to the .psm1, it does not need to be.  Instead, it should be simply the name of the module folder **if** the location to which the module folder is deployed in the PSModulePath.